# Android: Is there a way to switch the spinner array based on user input from other activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am a beginner in Android development. I am trying to make an app for a class project. During registration (Registration activity) the user can choose any continent from the spinner. In another activity, the user gets to choose countries depending on what continent the user had chosen before from the spinner on registration activity. I already have different arrays in my string.xml file.

My thought process is, in the second activity, if the user chose Asia, this layout will have the spinner display countries in Asia. If the user chose Europe, the spinner will display countries in Europe (array from strings.xml)
example of my array on string.xml

```
 <string-array name="asia">
    <item>"India"</item>
    <item>"pakistan"</item>
    <item>"China"</item>
    <item>"Japan"</item>
    <item>"Bangladesh"</item>
</string-array>
```

I also have a string array for Europe and other continents. I have a spinner on my layout, but I don't know how to implement the different arrays based on user input from first activity. I haven't assigned any arrays/options on my spinner yet. Any kind of help/suggestions/resource/advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: sounds like a basic if/switch statement, no ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody yeah, i have the if else statement, but idk how to use the spinner, idk how to get the string array from XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either have a method in your second activity which updates the spinners adapter with a string array.

Or you could have a public variable as an array which acts as your selected array. This array could be updated based on the selected state of the spinner. Then you can access this array from your second activity and use it when you set the adapter of your spinner.

The last one of the two is probably the easiest.

Here is an example of how you could do it. First activity contains a spinner and a button which takes you to the second

First activity:

```
//The spinner in the first activity
Spinner spinner;

//the lists that we use in our spinner
public List<String> asiaList = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> europeList = new ArrayList<String>();

//Our selected array
public List<String> selectedArray = new ArrayList<String>();


public static MainActivity mainActivity;

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainActivity = this;


    //Getting the xml arrays into our lists
    getListInfo(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.asia), asiaList);
    getListInfo(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.europe), europeList);



    //Your spinner
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Items in your first spinner;
    categories.add("Asia");
    categories.add("Europe");

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    // Drop down layout style
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    //Isn't necessary and can be done by using spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //If asia is selected
            if(position == 0){
                selectedArray = asiaList;
            }else{
                selectedArray = europeList;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


}
//function for your button to open next activity
public void OpenSecondActivity(View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
secondActivity.selectedArray = selectedArray;


        

}


//Put xml strings into your array lists;
public void getListInfo(String[] strings, List<String> list){
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        list.add(strings[i]);
    }


}
```

Second Activity:

```
//Spinner second class
Spinner spinner;

public static List<String> selectedArray = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);


    // Creating adapter for spinner and also reference the current list from first activity to get right info
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, selectedArray);

    // Drop down layout style
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}
```

The strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="asia">
    <item>"India"</item>
    <item>"pakistan"</item>
    <item>"China"</item>
    <item>"Japan"</item>
    <item>"Bangladesh"</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="europe">
    <item>"Sweden"</item>
    <item>"England"</item>
    <item>"Spain"</item>
    <item>"Norway"</item>
    <item>"Germany"</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Do I need to make an adapter for this? Is it possible for you to show me an example code? So the string array In my string.xml is useless? :/

Comment: @csstudent Now I have edited my answer with code. I think you will need the adapter as I showed in the answer. The Strings in your xml can absolutely be used as long as you use the "getListInfo" func. I hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Hey thanks for the code! I just tried it and it gave me an error "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read on a null object reference" and it pointed to "ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MainActivity.mainActivity.selectedArray);" on the second activity :/ Any ideas/help?

Comment: Is your app opening the second activity before the first one has been initialized? Because then this error would be because you haven't created the selected array yet. If this is the case you could try and move the selected string to the second activity.

Comment: No, My first activity is a fragment, I click a button in the fragment, and that should open the second activity :/

Comment: Ok, which activity is holding the fragment / parent activity?

Comment: When using fragments the error you are getting is caused by the fragment closing before you can access the variable. I have changed the code so now it should be working. Note that you will have to use secondActivity.selectedArray = selectedArray;
directly after you start the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/spinner#kotlin

I adecuate the sample function in the above link to "switch" between Volume or Weight units arrays:

```
private fun refillSpinner(radioChoiceVolWei: Int) {
    val fromSpinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.from_units)

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this,
        radioChoiceVolWei, // Reference to the Res string-array
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    ).also { adapter ->
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        fromSpinner.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Then I call the function with:

```
    refillSpinner(R.array.weight_units_array)
```

or

```
    refillSpinner(R.array.volume_units_array)
```

Where the arrays are somehow like yours:

```
<string-array name="weight_units_array">
    <item>kilogram</item>
    <item>gram</item>
    <item>ounce</item>
</string-array>
```

and

```
<string-array name="volume_units_array">
    <item>litre</item>
    <item>millilitre</item>
    <item>ounce</item>
</string-array>
```

Regards.